# Suggest list in google maps search input

Tags: search, google-maps, autosuggest

We need to create search input field like it is on _http://maps.google.com 
The key functionality is suggest list with appropriate results. We 
have not found this feature in API.

Analyzing maps.google.com we see that suggest list is received 
from get request to this url 
https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/suggest?q=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81&cp=... 
There are many parameters, including data from search field. This get 
request returns our suggest list.

Is there a possibility to use this url in our needs with our data. Or 
how can we make it in some other way.

Similar to our needs: _http://cdn.michaelhart.me/mh/instant/maps/

Comment: Have you tried googling "google suggest api"?

Comment: yep, but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 4):

check this out:
http://tech.cibul.net/geocode-with-google-maps-api-v3/

Comment: The answer is from Feb of 2011, your comment is over two months later. It's not his fault that the page was removed some time in between.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you shouldn't use maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/suggest as it might not be legal. I found this quote from google employee:

'Endpoints like this that are used by Google Maps but not documented as
part of the Maps API should be considered private interfaces.
Consequently use of those end points is a breach of the Terms of
Service. In addition any existing API credentials you may have are
completely unrelated to these end points because they are not served
by API infrastructure'